# Python3 decode bytes

Tags: python-3.x, encode

Trying to **decode** bytes

```
2k2P3PKIfViQ1L6TTc7kYks6bpeat6pPH9qRrNcj1S2195TYz\x88}\x88\x88JKgqzeXz96zKrTX05D9bkJf1yCf
```

Is there a way to convert ***\x88*** to ***letter*** or ***hide it***.

trying this

```
s = b'2k2P3PKIfViQ1L6TTc7kYks6bpeat6pPH9qRrNcj1S2195TYz\x88}\x88\x88JKgqzeXz96zKrTX05D9bkJf1yCf'
d = s.decode('utf-8')
```

but got error

```
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 64: invalid start byte
```

Any Help?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: *How do I decode this random string I've posted?* isn't really an answerable question. Where did that string come from?

Comment: @KenWhite i want to covert it to `u+0088`

Comment: You can't magically convert it to utf-8 by decoding if it's not UTF-8 content in the first place. Again, **where did the string come from** in the first place, and what makes you think it should be UTF-8 encoded? Throwing random strings into the decode function without knowing anything about that random string isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it's UTF-8? UTF-8 is a *specific*, *self-checking* encoding, you can't just decode random bytes with it. If you just want to convert every byte to the equivalent Unicode ordinal, decode with `latin-1`. Decoding with `cp1252` will even make a useful printable character. Or choose any other one byte per character ASCII encoding and see what it looks like. With no idea what it's supposed to *mean*, any 1-1 bytes to text encoding *works*, it's the logic of your program that determines if it's correct.

Comment: i want to covert to `u+0088`. is there a way??

Comment: @CamBoKiDz: Yeah, that's the first one I suggested, `latin-1`, which is a strict byte value to equivalent Unicode ordinal mapping. It'll still look like `\x88` in the result (it's not a printable character, it's a C1 control code), but it'll successfully decode.

Comment: i want use that encrypt to send ***json***. However, i can't since it contain \x88

Comment: You want it to convert to the actual string `'u+0088'`, not the Unicode literal value associated you could get with `\u0088`?

Comment: yeah, it is. :(

Comment: @CamBoKiDz: Can you just do: `re.sub(rb'[\x80-\xff]', lambda m: b'u+00%02x' % m[0][0], s).decode('ascii')` or something to manually convert the non-ASCII bytes to the preferred form, then decode it all as ASCII? There's a similar option where you decode as `latin-1` first, then use `str.maketrans`+`str.translate`, or `re.sub` to replace string-wise, but it's all pretty similar.

Comment: thanks, but still, that not i want.

Comment: can u go this link https://gist.github.com/g3tl0st/b31d04e082a30e409e15b627f1240c0e??

Comment: can u make it to hidden character??

Comment: @CamBoKiDz: Hidden, or discarded? You can replace them with *anything* or just delete them, but either way, you'd lose the ability to recover the original bytes, and you keep being cagey/unclear about what you actually want here. `.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')` is sufficient to throw all non-ASCII characters away, but you'll never recover the original bytes.